# Sending HTML data through AJAX to a PHP script

Tags: php, ajax

I have created a WYSIWYG text editor for my site and am trying to save the contents to a DB.

I get the contents of my iframe where the text editor is like so:

```
var product_description = richTextField.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
```

I then send it via AJAX like so:

```
var query_string = "product_edit_parse.php?";
query_string += "desc="+product_description;
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("POST", query_string, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

However, I get an error

```
[Deprecation] Resource requests whose URLs contained both removed whitespace (`\n`, `\r`, `\t`) characters and less-than characters (`<`) are blocked. Please remove newlines and encode less-than characters from places like element attribute values in order to load these resources. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5735596811091968 for more details.
```

What is the best way to handle this data if the file I'm sending to needs to deal with this data in PHP?

Comment: You should send the data in the body of the request. Not in the url.

Comment: I also agree with @Ivar your ajax request is being sent via post so you should probably send the product description via post as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your string `product_description` has HTML and whitespace in it, if you want to escape / sanitize this string you can try `encodeURIComponent`

```
var product_description = richTextField.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;

var query_string = "product_edit_parse.php?";
query_string += "desc="+encodeURIComponent(product_description);
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("POST", query_string, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

If you're only grabbing a description of the product I'd encourage you to give the parent element a class or ID so you can grab it specifically